# how to make dynamic graph size based on the size of tibble in R？

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

I have different size tibbles(cols. are the same, rows vary) in a list.

Here is an example of the tibbles:

```
parts1 <- c("KNA00197J-AN", "KNA00007J-PF", "KNA00007J-PF", "KNA00009J-PF", "KNA00022JB-AN",    "KNA00009J-PF", "KSB00026J-PQ", "KSB00027J-PQ", "KSB00029J-PQ", "KSB00023J-PQ", "KSB00065J-PQ", "KSB00187J-PQ", "KSB00031JB-PQ",    "KSB00060J-AN", "KSD00042J",    "KSD00030J",    "KSD00033J",    "KSD00040J",    "KSD00043J",    "KNA00029J",    "KNA00035J",    "KSD00036J",    "KND00003J",    "KSD00053J",    "KSD00029J",    "KSD00032J",    "KSA00030J",    "KSD00074J",    "KSD00078J",    "KSE00031J",    "KSE00032J")
value1 <- c(300,100,200,200,200,200,562,336,623,415,182,145,640,563,286,264,264,312,286,72,60,286,8,360,264,264,154,1440,1024,52,32)

parts2 <- c("KNA00197J-AN", "KNA00007J-PF", "KNA00007J-PF", "KNA00009J-PF", "KNA00022JB-AN")
value2 <- c(300,100,200,200,200)

df1 <- data.frame(parts = parts1, value = value1)
df2 <- data.frame(parts = parts2, value = value2)

list_df <- list(df1,df2)
```

Now, I use ggplot to make a bar graph for these tibbles in the list and knit to pdf.

```
for(n in 1:length(list_df)){
  pic<- ggplot(list_df[[n]], aes(x = value, y =parts ))+
    geom_col(position = "dodge", width=0.5)
  
  print(pic)
}
```

The graphs are the same size. Can we make it automatically change size in order to make them easy to read based on tibble's parts number?

like, make df1 graph spread longer on y axis.

Thank you a lot!

Comment: Welcome! Is there a reason that you do not want to combine the data into one plot? That would take care of this problem in a much neater way than scaling the plot outputs manually.

Comment: There are multiple parts in each tibble. Which part will you consider for size ?

Comment: These tibbles are separated by a condition. Some times we could have more tibbles based on the condition. Each tibble could have different number of rows. For those that have a lot rows, the bins are not crammed on y axis. For those that don't have very many rows, the bins are not so fat. Can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want each plot in a separate pdf file, then you could do something like this where i use the `height` argument, to the `ggsave` function, to adjust the height of the plot according to the number of rows.

As default the height is measured in inches, so to not add a whole inch per row i scaled the height a factor of 3 so that each row will add 1/3 of an inch to the plot.

```
library(tidyverse)

parts1 <- c("KNA00197J-AN", "KNA00007J-PF", "KNA00007J-PF", "KNA00009J-PF", "KNA00022JB-AN",    "KNA00009J-PF", "KSB00026J-PQ", "KSB00027J-PQ", "KSB00029J-PQ", "KSB00023J-PQ", "KSB00065J-PQ", "KSB00187J-PQ", "KSB00031JB-PQ",    "KSB00060J-AN", "KSD00042J",    "KSD00030J",    "KSD00033J",    "KSD00040J",    "KSD00043J",    "KNA00029J",    "KNA00035J",    "KSD00036J",    "KND00003J",    "KSD00053J",    "KSD00029J",    "KSD00032J",    "KSA00030J",    "KSD00074J",    "KSD00078J",    "KSE00031J",    "KSE00032J")
value1 <- c(300,100,200,200,200,200,562,336,623,415,182,145,640,563,286,264,264,312,286,72,60,286,8,360,264,264,154,1440,1024,52,32)

parts2 <- c("KNA00197J-AN", "KNA00007J-PF", "KNA00007J-PF", "KNA00009J-PF", "KNA00022JB-AN")
value2 <- c(300,100,200,200,200)

df1 <- data.frame(parts = parts1, value = value1)
df2 <- data.frame(parts = parts2, value = value2)

list_df <- list(df1,df2)

scale_factor <- 3
for(n in 1:length(list_df)){
  print(n)
  ggplot(list_df[[n]], aes(x = value, y =parts )) +
    geom_col(position = "dodge", width=0.5)
  
  ggsave(paste0('plot_',n,'.pdf'), height=nrow(list_df[[n]])/scale_factor, width=6)
}
```

Comment: Great. It saves to pdf with nice auto-adjust y axis, but I'm trying to knit it as a whole pdf. But great help. Can we knit it as a whole pdf which showing these pictures?

Comment: , cause I run this as Rmd file.

Comment: I could foresee some problems with trying to knit it as a pdf if the plots get too long to fit on one page, then you would maybe have some upper bound on the size of the plot or what would you want to do in this case?

Comment: Yea. It is difficult to knit in pdf... How about HTML? Can we make is look nicer? In HTML, I made the 2 df into one big df and facet_wrap by a condition( let's say the first df below to firm1; the second df below to firm 2) . The facet plot was also same size of y axis regardless the rows.